# При любого ввода комманды в putty возникает ошибка: -bash: /usr/bin/php5: No such file or directory

Tags: putty

Здравствуйте, мой проект находится на удалённом хостинге reg.ru и в самом проекте мне нужно загрузить модуль, я подключилась через ssh к командной строке putty и при любого ввода команды возникает ошибка: -bash: /usr/bin/php5: No such file or directory. В чём может проблема, почему не запускается команда?

Вот собственно что я вводила и какая ошибка следом пошла:

```
login as: u*******
u*******@**.**.***.***'s password:

u*******@u*******.cp.regruhosting.ru [~]# cd /var/www/u*******/public_html/site.ru

u*******@u*******.cp.regruhosting.ru [~/public_html/site.ru]# php composer require komer45/yii2-balance "*" (После ввода этой команды вылетает:)

-bash: /usr/bin/php5: No such file or directory

u*******@u*******.cp.regruhosting.ru [~/public_html/site.ru]#
```

Comment: а сама команда выполняется? ошибка до или после вывода команды? может в PS1 какая-то ерунда? да и вообще `env` стоит грепнуть по 'php'...

Comment: @Fat-Zer В самом вопросе я добавила ту ошибку которая вылетает и саму команду. Может сможете направить меня хотя-бы куда копать

Comment: на `cd` же не выводит? дык, может php просто не установлен или установлен седьмой, а симлинк `/usr/bin/php` остался указывать на пятый...

Comment: @Fat-Zer а как можно проверить версию php в putty? Просто при вводе команды php -v выходит такая же ошибка: u*******@u*******.cp.regruhosting.ru [~/public_html/site.ru]# php -v
-bash: /usr/bin/php5: No such file or directory

Comment: @ГаленкоСветлана, на хостинге то php есть? Если да, то обратитесь в службу поддержки хостинга

Comment: @ГаленкоСветлана, зависит от того, что за система на хосте... по форме приглашения ЕМНИП похожа на что-то шляпа-based... `grep . /etc/*release*` для определённости... если угадал, тогда проверить можно чем-то вроде `yum list installed 'php.*'`, а установить `yum install php`

Comment: Спасибо большое но наверное я попробую подключиться к сайту через phpStorm, так как борюсь с этой ошибкой уже 3 дня.. Может он прокатит без ошибок)

Comment: Вообщем попыталась я подключиться через phpStorm и после ввода команды произошла такая же ошибка ... Значит что-то не то со стороны сервака....

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто на хостинге в файле поменять путь к исполняемому файлу php

```
alias php='/usr/bin/php5'
```

на

```
alias php='/opt/php/5.6/bin/php'!
```